# Remove first x number of characters from each row in a column of a Python dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas dataframe with about 1,500 rows and 15 columns. For one specific column, I would like to remove the first 3 characters of each row. As a simple example here is a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'Report Number':['8761234567', '8679876543','8994434555'],
    'Name'         :['George', 'Bill', 'Sally']
     }

d = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to remove the first three characters from each field in the `Report Number` column of dataframe `d`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods to slice each string entry

```
In [11]:
d['Report Number'] = d['Report Number'].str[3:]
d

Out[11]:
     Name Report Number
0  George       1234567
1    Bill       9876543
2   Sally       4434555
```

Answer (score 7):

It is worth noting Pandas "vectorised" `str` methods are no more than Python-level loops.

Assuming clean data, you will often find a list comprehension more efficient:

```
# Python 3.6.0, Pandas 0.19.2

d = pd.concat([d]*10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit d['Report Number'].str[3:]           # 12.1 ms per loop
%timeit [i[3:] for i in d['Report Number']]  # 5.78 ms per loop
```

Note these aren't equivalent, since the list comprehension does not deal with null data and other edge cases. For these situations, you may prefer the Pandas solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also call [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html). To remove the first 3 characters from each string:

```py
df['Report Number'] = df['Report Number'].str.slice(3)
```

To slice the 2-4th characters from each string:

```py
df['Report Number'] = df['Report Number'].str.slice(1, 4)
```