# change index name in python

Tags: python, indexing, rename

I would like to reset the name of the indices in a DataFrame in python to the same name with the first number dropped.

For example if my DataFrame is:

```
                 Sample 1                Sample 2
    2706   retinopathy positive        retinopathy negative
    2707   retinopathy negative        retinopathy negative
    2708   retinopathy positive        retinopathy positive
```

I want it to become:

```
                Sample 1                 Sample 2
     706   retinopathy positive        retinopathy negative
     707   retinopathy negative        retinopathy negative
     708   retinopathy positive        retinopathy positive
```

I have tried:

```
ret_metadata.rename(index={2706: '706'})
```

However I would like to change the index name for many different rows, maybe in a loop. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string operations as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349572/remove-first-x-number-of-characters-from-each-row-in-a-column-of-a-python-datafr) by casting it to a string, slicing it, and casting it back to int.

```
df

        Sample_1                Sample_2
2706    retinopathy_positive    retinopathy_negative
2707    retinopathy_negative    retinopathy_negative
2708    retinopathy_positive    retinopathy_positive
```

(You can skip the second cast if you don't care about the index being numeric)

```
df.index=df.index.astype(str).str[1:].astype(int)

df

    Sample_1                Sample_2
706 retinopathy_positive    retinopathy_negative
707 retinopathy_negative    retinopathy_negative
708 retinopathy_positive    retinopathy_positive

df.index

Int64Index([706, 707, 708], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a mathematical solution (no conversion to string) you could do something like this:

```py
import math
# ...
df.index = df.index % (pow(10, int(math.log(df.index, 10))))
```

... when you always want to remove the first digit.

If you want to remove all but the last three digits it becomes much simpler:

```py
df.index = df.index % 1000
```

Comment: Thank you very much yaccob!